# Getting different sharedpreferences for different appWidgets

Tags: java, android, configuration, android-widget, sharedpreferences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add several appWidgets with different configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962524/add-several-appwidgets-with-different-configuration)

I have a widget which displays a simple textview, which is editable as an edittextfield in a configuration activity. I'm trying to make it possible to add several widgets to the homescreen with different textconfigurations, fx. one widget display: "Buy a lamp.." and another one saying: "I love Bacon".

My problem is that the widgets keeps displaying the same text, and if I edit one widget the other one changes too. I'm using sharedpreferences to save the inputted data for later re-configuration. (I am not using PreferenceActivity)

I've been struggling with this for hours, any help would be much appreciated.

Why doesn't this work:

```
SharedPreferences sp;
EditText info;
String note;
int appWidgetId;

private void loadPrefs(){
        sp = context.getSharedPreferences("widget" + String.valueOf(appWidgetId)
              , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        note = sp.getString("Note", "");

        info.setText(note);

    }

    private void savePrefs(String key, String value){
        sp = context.getSharedPreferences("widget" + String.valueOf(appWidgetId)
                  , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.putString("Note", info.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();   

    }
```

and then i have a confirm button to end configuration, which calls the savePrefs method

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        savePrefs("Note", info.getText().toString());
```

Full code configuration activity code:

```
import java.io.File;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.style.StyleSpan;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class WidgetConfig extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener {


    AppWidgetManager awm;
    int awID;
    Context context;
    EditText info;
    Button b;
    String note;
    int styleStart = -1, cursorLoc = 0;
    int appWidgetId;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    Spinner spinner;
    String[] paths = { "10", "20", "30" };
    File path = null;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.widgetconfig);

        context = WidgetConfig.this;
        info = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etwidgetconfig);


            ...


        b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bwidgetconfig);
        loadPrefs();
        b.setOnClickListener(this);


        //Getting Info about the widget that launched this activity
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
        if (extras != null){
            awID = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
            AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID );
        }

        awm = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

    }


        ...


    private void loadPrefs(){
        sp = context.getSharedPreferences("widget" + String.valueOf(appWidgetId)
              , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        note = sp.getString("Note", "");

        info.setText(note);

    }

    private void savePrefs(String key, String value){
        sp = context.getSharedPreferences("widget" + String.valueOf(appWidgetId)
                  , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.putString("Note", info.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();   

    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        savePrefs("Note", info.getText().toString());

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvConfigInput, info.getText());

        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(this, Widget.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
        manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, views);

        Intent in = new Intent(context, WidgetConfig.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);



        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.B_EditAgain, pi);

        awm.updateAppWidget(awID, views);


        Intent result = new Intent();
        result.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, awID);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
        finish();

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh cool, so just set appWidgetId to awID. or even simpler, pass the awID to the methods you are calling sharedPreferences. That should fix it.

Comment: if you mean just replacing sp = context.getSharedPreferences("widget" + String.valueOf(appWidgetId), Context.MODE_PRIVATE); in both save- and loadPrefs, with: sp = context.getSharedPreferences("widget" + String.valueOf(awID), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);     Then yes, that's what i've beeen thinking, and i've tried it before, and it's doesn't fix it. any other suggestions?

Comment: So that means that the widget Id is not set when intent is created.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html